# Issue with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to set up horizontal scrolling tabs, and I've seen people saying use a ViewPager.

Ive got it partly working, I can vertically scroll between my fragments, but I don't get any tabs at the top to select a different tab.

Here's my code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

```
MyPageAdapter pageAdapter;
Context ctx;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    ctx = this;

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    assert actionBar != null;

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("tab", 0));
    }

    List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();
    pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
}

private List<Fragment> getFragments(){
    List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    fList.add(MyFragment.newInstance("MyFragment 1"));
    fList.add(MyFragment.newInstance("MyFragment 2"));
    fList.add(MyFragment.newInstance("MyFragment 3"));

    return fList;
}



class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }
}
```

I'm also including the v4 support library

```
dependencies {
    compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0', 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36')
    compile files('/libs/android-async-http-1.4.3.jar')
}
```

However, in my XML layout I get an warning saying Element android.support.v4.view.ViewPager is not allowed here.

Have I not including the library correctly and is this why I don't see any tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **add tabs to your ActionBar**.

Do it like that:

```
final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        bar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

        mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Tab 1"),
                YourFragment.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Tab 2"),
                YourFragment.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Tab 3"),
                YourFragment.class, null);
```

Also, you will need a `ActionBar.TabListener` and a `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` to let the ViewPager change to the selected page when a tab is pressed.

See here for a full example: **http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html**

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to have an action bar, if you just want to display the page titles it can be achieved by changing your layout to

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
    android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="#33b5e5"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

as with the example [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#PagerTitleStrip), but you still need to create a custom [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html).

This is how I have done it in my android 2.3.5 application.